# Facebook key hash doesn't work

Tags: android, facebook, ionic-framework

I sent a new version of my app to Google Play and the key hash changed. I used Ionic package to generate the apk.

When I try to connect with Facebook on app, I receive the following error:

> Invalid key hash. The key hash ***** does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at https://developers.facebook....

The problem is that the hash is configured on Facebook and I checked this a lot of times.

Answer (score 0):

> "invalid key hash. the key {your_key} hash does not match any stored key hashes. configured your app key hashes release apk".

Just copy {your_key} into "key hash" of facebook console and save.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I solved that, I just forgot to mark as solved. Actually, my hash had some letters like this: " lI ", can you see the difference? These are tiny "L" and capital "i". and I can't copy, I had to write. After some tryings, I solved.